# Is there a webcam that can focus to infinity, for time-lapse landscapes?

Tags: focus, timelapse, infrared, webcam

Does anyone here know of a webcam (at least 720p) that has the ability to focus to infinity?

At least one webcam I know of (Logitech C910) doesn't allow that.

I would like to use it for time lapse photography of landscapes (including in Infrared).

Comment: This is you... isn't it - http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Webcams/C910-Cannot-focus-at-infinity/td-p/604366 or even http://forums.quickcamteam.net/showthread.php?tid=1682

Comment: I would take a look on Youtube for "timelapse" + "webcam" and see what you find. I'm not able to access Youtube currently or I would give it a shot. Google wasn't very helpful in finding me any answers to this one.

Comment: @dpollitt: No, it is not. But I also found that very link before, which is why I want to research this thoroughly before I pay 60+ bucks for something that doesn't do what I want.

Comment: Looking on youtube now, but most videos I found so far are low quality and a couple of years old (hence, do not demonstrate a modern HD camera in action).

Comment: Is there some reason you want a webcam for this purpose? Is there some reason you are not looking at a DSLR with an intervolometer to do time-lapse landscape photography?

Comment: There are webcams that *can't* focus to infinity? WTF were they thinking?

Comment: I had the same problem with C615 logitech, bought litecam studio, have same problem again. Cameras do not focus on infinity.

Comment: @jrista I can't speak for the OP, but for me: Long-term timelapse. Because I worry about shutter wear (entry-level DSLR 50k shutter actuations = 30 min video @ 30fps). Because of weather-proofing - not that webcams are weatherproof, but I expect they can handle more abuse than the average SLR. Because I don't want to be without a camera for 6 months (assume I want a winter-spring-summer time lapse). Because the loss of a €100 webcam, if it breaks or gets stolen, is less than the loss of a €1000 DSLR. If there are better options, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 4):

My [Orbit](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/38/3480) will. Even has Zeiss glass and pan, tilt, and zoom. Timelapse example [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o19fpAkXAbM).

Comment: Hmm...wonder whats with the semi-creepy music in the sample. ;P

Comment: No idea. Not my sample - just a random youtube link.  I can personally guarantee that owning this camera will not incline you to play creepy music ;).

Answer (score 2):

I have a Microsoft LifeCam Studio, and it can focus to infinity (it's AF).

I don't know how easy it would be to remove the IR filter, though. It's basically an aluminium tube.

Answer (score 0):

My first recommendation is going to be the [Logitech Quickcam Vision Pro 9000](http://www.logitech.com/webcam-communications/webcams/devices/6333). I do not have first hand experience, but based off of [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GE3rrjgHe98&hd=1) Youtube video, I would say it does what you are looking for(with the exclusion of infrared which can be added).

Beyond that, I think you are really looking for a professional grade webcam that is meant to be used outdoors, and include features like pan, tilt, and optical zoom. I do not have experience with these.

Comment: Interestingly, the Pro 9000 is said to have the same problem in the Logitech forum link you provided in the 1st comment to the question.